# What is this Makefile Doing?

Tags: makefile

I'm new using makefiles and I have some makefiles.  One of them has these statements I tried to understand but I can't.

#### What is this makefile doing?

```
# debugging support
ifeq ($(DEBUG), true)
CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG -g
endif 

ifeq ($(DEBUG), gdb)
CFLAGS+=-g
endif

ifeq ($(PROFILING), true)
CFLAGS+=-p
endif

# symbolic names debugging
ifeq ($(DEBUG_NAMES), true)
CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG_NAMES
endif 

# architecture TODO: add others
ifeq ($(ARCH), unix)
CFLAGS+=-DUNIX
endif

# TODO: GC settings
ifeq ($(HEAP), malloc)
CFLAGS+=-DHEAP_MALLOC
endif

ifeq ($(STACK), malloc)
CFLAGS+=-DSTACK_MALLOC
endif

# class loading method
ifeq ($(CLASS), external)
CFLAGS+=-DEXTERNAL_TUK
endif

# monitor allocation
ifeq ($(MONITORS), ondemand)
CFLAGS+=-DON_DEMAND_MONITORS
endif
```

Amri

Comment: Now that this question has been edited into something resembling coherence, maybe those of us who voted it down can reverse our negative votes?

Comment: I have no idea why this question is voted down, but I voted it up .. (still -3)

Comment: Anybody want to diagnose the dialect of make?  I am not immediately sure whether it is GNU Make or some Microfaustian version.  I use portable makefile constructs (or, attempt to), so I don't use these notations.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially the makefile is doing a bunch of checks and adding compiler flags based on the state of certain variables. For instance:

```
ifeq ($(DEBUG), true)

CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG -g

endif
```

If the DEBUG variable $(DEBUG) is set to true, then define the macro DEBUG, and set the compiler to output debug binaries (-g).

Every other statement is roughly the same pattern.

Comment: could you tell me please, what is CFLAGS options or values could be

Comment: Have a look at how CFlags is used - it is probably passed to GCC. In that case, have a look at gcc's man page (i.e type man GCC at the command line on a linux system or google for some detail)

Answer (score 5):

This checks for the values of environmental variables and configures the build process with specific options for the compiler ( I think ) .

Comment: They don't have to be environmental variables; you can also give them on the command line, as in "make DEBUG=gdb ARCH=unix".

Answer (score 2):

CFLAGS is a string of arguments that will be passed to the C compiler when it is called.

If you don't know what the arguments mean, you need to look at the help for your C compiler.  For example:

```
man cc
man gcc
cc --help
gcc --help
```